# iOS swift extracting permalink from deeplink URL

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing Firebase dynamic links in my iOS project. It is working fine and it is opening my iOS Home screen properly. But now I would like to extract values from url and open appropriate screen based on url.

for example:
      https://www.dd.com/forums/hot-deals-online/topics/smart-tv-carniva

in this url I would like to get 'hot-deals-online' and 'smart-tv-carniva' permalink which I will pass to view controller to open that screen on the app

can someone suggest me best approach for this.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest is to access `path` of `URLComponents` object:

```
let url = "https://www.dd.com/forums/hot-deals-online/topics/smart-tv-carniva"

if let comps = URLComponents(string: url) {
    var elements = comps.path.split(separator: "/").map(String.init)
    // ["forums", "hot-deals-online", "topics", "smart-tv-carniva"]


    // To build an url back, example:
    var url = URL(string: comps.host!)!
    url.appendPathComponent(elements[0])
    url.appendPathComponent(elements[1])
    // Result: www.dd.com/forums/hot-deals-online
}
```

P.S. calling `.map(String.init)` makes in-place conversion from array of substrings to normal `String` array.

Comment: problem with this is how to map other urls?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: what if I have url like https://www.dd.com/users/1... I get the array but how should I know which screen to open?

Comment: Array contains path components. If it contains `users` and the last component is an `Int`, then it's obvious that you need to open screen fro particular user. You will need to write algorithm to check for all possible inclusions, from top-level to the deepest. For users, if `users` is contained in the array, then check if it's the deepest (=last) element. If no, then seek an ID. If id is there, then you need a screen for particular user.